# .ist file has no effect on printed index

Tags: imakeidx, makeindex

I am trying to modify an index with a style `.ist` file. I create the `.ist` file, I place it in the same directory as the main file, and pass the option. However, the index remains the same.

Here there is a MWE of my `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools, amsthm}
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\normalfont\bfseries, notefont=\bfseries, bodyfont=\normalfont, shaded={rulecolor=black,rulewidth=0.5pt,bgcolor={rgb}{1,1,1},margin=5pt,textwidth=11.8cm}, notebraces={}{:}, headpunct={}, postheadspace=1em]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{proposition}
\declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\normalfont\bfseries, numbered=no, notefont=\bfseries, bodyfont=\footnotesize, shaded={rulecolor=gray,rulewidth=0.5pt,bgcolor={rgb}{1,1,1},margin=5pt,textwidth=11.8cm}, qed=\qedsymbol, notebraces={--- }{:}, headpunct={}, postheadspace=1em]{mystyle5}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle5]{proof}
\declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\normalfont\bfseries, shaded={rulecolor=black,rulewidth=0.5pt,margin=5pt,textwidth=11.8cm}, notebraces={}{:}, headpunct={}, postheadspace=1em]{mystyle3}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle3]{definition}

\numberwithin{proposition}{section}
\numberwithin{definition}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage[splitindex,nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=proposition,title=Index of Propositions, options={-s index.ist}]
\makeindex[name=definition,title=Index of Definitions, options={-s index.ist}]
\makeindex[name=figure,title=Index of Figures, options={-s index.ist}]

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\Roman{figure}.}
\renewcommand{\thedefinition}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\Alph{definition}.}
\renewcommand{\theproposition}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{proposition}.}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}[\textbf{WHATEVER1}]\index[proposition]{prop1}
    BLABLABLA   
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}[\textbf{WHATEVER2}]\index[proposition]{prop6}
    BLABLABLA   
\end{proposition}

\begin{definition}[\textbf{LOL1}]\index[definition]{def1}
    LOREM IPSUM 
\end{definition}

\begin{proposition}[\textbf{WHATEVER3}]\index[proposition]{prop5}
    BLABLABLA   
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}[\textbf{WHATEVER4}]\index[proposition]{prop4}
    BLABLABLA   
\end{proposition}

\begin{definition}[\textbf{LOL2}]\index[definition]{def4}
    LOREM IPSUM 
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}[\textbf{LOL3}]\index[definition]{def3}
    LOREM IPSUM 
\end{definition}

\begin{proposition}[\textbf{WHATEVER5}]\index[proposition]{prop3}
    BLABLABLA   
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}[\textbf{WHATEVER6}]\index[proposition]{prop2}
    BLABLABLA   
\end{proposition}

\begin{definition}[\textbf{LOL4}]\index[definition]{def2}
    LOREM IPSUM 
\end{definition}

\printindex[proposition]
\printindex[definition]

\end{document}
```

Here goes my `.ist` file:

```
headings_flag 1

heading_prefix "\n\\centering\\large\\sffamily\\bfseries%
\\noindent\\textbf{"heading_suffix "}\\par\\nopagebreak\n"

item_0 "\n \\item \\small "

delim_0 " \\hfill "
delim_1 " \\hfill "
delim_2 " \\hfill "
```

See here how the output is the default one, which means that my .ist file is not having any effect:

[image]

Why is NOT the `.ist` file affecting the output? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `options` key can only be honored without the `splitindex` option, because the production of the indices is handed over to that program and there's no way to pass options to it automatically.

You can do

```
splitindex -m "makeindex -s index" <filename>
```

when you do the call. The obvious limitation is that just one style can be passed to each index.

Just remove the `splitindex` option and `imakeidx` will honor the chosen style.

Comment: @Héctor Leave out also the `nonewpage` option: it makes little sense with `report`.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, I will! However, going back to the original question, if I remove that option and I keep the rest of the code as it is, it produces no index. I am afraid my limited LaTex knowledge does not allow me to fully understand your (quick) reply. How do I get multiple indices with a custom style? That is, what other changes do I need to apply to my code? Please, could you elaborate further on that?